# Не отображаются цифры в input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Изменяю .textContent у input, а цифры не отображаются. Пробовал изменять z-index, не помогло. Вопрос - в чем проблема? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```js
//Развёртка зелёного меню//

let greenString = document.querySelector('.greenString');
let outputPanel = document.querySelector('.outputPanel');
let closers = document.querySelectorAll('.closer');
let numbersTable = document.querySelector('.numbersTable');
greenString.addEventListener('click', function(b) {
  greenString.classList.add('active');
  numbersTable.classList.add('activeNumbersTable');
  document.querySelector('.greenTable').classList.remove('hide');
});
closers.forEach(function function_name(argument) {
  argument.addEventListener('click', function(a) {
    numbersTable.classList.remove('activeNumbersTable');
    greenString.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.greenTable').classList.add('hide');
  });
});

//Вывод цифр в табло//

let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
numbers.forEach(function smt(num) {
  num.addEventListener('click', function(c) {
    console.log(outputPanel.textContent)
    console.log(num.textContent)
    outputPanel.textContent = outputPanel.textContent + num.textContent;
  });
})
```

```css
@import src('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 570px;
  width: 288px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.numbersTable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: sans serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.outputPanel {
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 43px;
  height: 145px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: none;
  -webkit-writing-mode: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

td {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.inpCell {
  height: 145px;
}

.operTable {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 160, 0.8);
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.tableCell {
  width: 20%;
}

.greenStringCell {
  width: 7.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.greenString {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(30, 255, 137, 1);
  transition: width 0.2s;
  height: 423px;
  right: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 7.5%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.active {
  width: 216px;
}

.activeNumbersTable {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.greenTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="numbersTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="inpCell"><input type="number" id="jopa" class="outputPanel" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">7</td>
      <td class="number">8</td>
      <td class="number">9</td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="tableCell">
        <table class="operTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>DEL</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&divide;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>+</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="greenStringCell">
        <div class="greenString">
          <table class="greenTable hide">
            <tr>
              <td>INV</td>
              <td>RAD</td>
              <td>%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>sin</td>
              <td>cos</td>
              <td>tan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>In</td>
              <td>log</td>
              <td>!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&pi;</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>^</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>(</td>
              <td>)</td>
              <td>&radic;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">4</td>
      <td class="number">5</td>
      <td class="number">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">1</td>
      <td class="number">2</td>
      <td class="number">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">,</td>
      <td class="number">0</td>
      <td class="equal">=</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо
`outputPanel.textContent = outputPanel.textContent + num.textContent;`

Используйте `outputPanel.value = outputPanel.value + num.textContent;`

Если конечно нужно что бы цифры просто добавлялись друг к другу в виде строки.

Answer (score 2):

У тега `input` нужно менять не `textContent`, а атрибут `value`.

```js
//Развёртка зелёного меню//

let greenString = document.querySelector('.greenString');
let outputPanel = document.querySelector('.outputPanel');
let closers = document.querySelectorAll('.closer');
let numbersTable = document.querySelector('.numbersTable');
greenString.addEventListener('click', function(b) {
  greenString.classList.add('active');
  numbersTable.classList.add('activeNumbersTable');
  document.querySelector('.greenTable').classList.remove('hide');
});
closers.forEach(function function_name(argument) {
  argument.addEventListener('click', function(a) {
    numbersTable.classList.remove('activeNumbersTable');
    greenString.classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelector('.greenTable').classList.add('hide');
  });
});

//Вывод цифр в табло//

let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
numbers.forEach(function smt(num) {
  num.addEventListener('click', function(c) {
    outputPanel.value += num.textContent;
  });
})
```

```css
@import src('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 570px;
  width: 288px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
}

.numbersTable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: sans serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.outputPanel {
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 43px;
  height: 145px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: none;
  -webkit-writing-mode: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

td {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

tr {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

.inpCell {
  height: 145px;
}

.operTable {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 160, 0.8);
  border: 0px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.tableCell {
  width: 20%;
}

.greenStringCell {
  width: 7.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.greenString {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(30, 255, 137, 1);
  transition: width 0.2s;
  height: 423px;
  right: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 7.5%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.active {
  width: 216px;
}

.activeNumbersTable {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.greenTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="numbersTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="inpCell"><input type="number" id="jopa" class="outputPanel" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">7</td>
      <td class="number">8</td>
      <td class="number">9</td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="tableCell">
        <table class="operTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>DEL</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&divide;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>+</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4" class="greenStringCell">
        <div class="greenString">
          <table class="greenTable hide">
            <tr>
              <td>INV</td>
              <td>RAD</td>
              <td>%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>sin</td>
              <td>cos</td>
              <td>tan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>In</td>
              <td>log</td>
              <td>!</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&pi;</td>
              <td>e</td>
              <td>^</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>(</td>
              <td>)</td>
              <td>&radic;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">4</td>
      <td class="number">5</td>
      <td class="number">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">1</td>
      <td class="number">2</td>
      <td class="number">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="number closer">,</td>
      <td class="number">0</td>
      <td class="equal">=</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```